# 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated warning when passing void* argument to c function in swift 5

Tags: c, swift, unsafe-pointers

I have a library parsing FIT file in swift using an externally provided c library. The parsing function takes as argument a `void * data`.
To call the function, I was converting the data using `data.withUnsafeBytes( { (ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in ...}` to build the argument to the c function and it was working fine.

After the upgrade of Xcode to swift 5, I now get a deprecated warning

'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

I couldn't work out how to fix the code to remove the deprecated warning. The code has been working fine and without warning in swift 4

I tried to change the argument in the closure to take `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` instead of the UnsafePointer but this resulted in an error in calling the function: `Cannot convert 'UnsafeRawBufferPointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafeRawPointer?'`

This is a small swift file to show the problem:

```swift
import Foundation

// Create sample data (Typically would be read from a file
let data = Data(repeating: 1, count: 10)

data.withUnsafeBytes( { (ptr : UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
    // call the c function with the void* argument
    let value = readFITfile(ptr)
    print( value )
})
```

And an example c function

```c
unsigned readFITfile(const void * data){
    //Silly example to show it works, just returning the value of pointer as int
    //Typically would parse the data and return a structure
    return (unsigned)data;
}
```

I saved a small repo with the above code here https://github.com/roznet/swift2c and the full scale project with the parsing of the file is here https://github.com/roznet/fit-sdk-swift

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to change the closure argument to `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` and then take its `baseAdress` (which is a `UnsafeRawPointer?`, the Swift equivalent of `void *` in C):

```
data.withUnsafeBytes( { (ptr : UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
    let value = readFITfile(ptr.baseAddress)
    // ...
})
```

The Swift compiler can also infer the closure argument type automatically:

```
data.withUnsafeBytes( { ptr in
    let value = readFITfile(ptr.baseAddress)
    // ...
})
```

For more information about this problem, see [withUnsafeBytes Data API confusion](https://forums.swift.org/t/withunsafebytes-data-api-confusion/22142) in the Swift forum.

Answer (score 3):

To get UnsafePointer now you should do something like that

```
data.withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
    if let ptrAddress = ptr.baseAddress, ptr.count > 0 {
        let pointer = ptrAddress.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) // here you got UnsafePointer<UInt8>
        let value = readFITfile(ptr)
        print( value )
    } else {
        // Here you should provide some error handling if you want ofc
    }
}
```

Comment: The given C function takes a `void *` argument, there is no need to convert the `UnsafeRawPointer` to `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`.

Comment: Btw, `ptr.baseAddress` *cannot* be `nil` for a non-empty buffer pointer.